# Modify figure sizes of `pr_curve` and `auc_curve` from R package yardstick

Tags: r, ggplot2, yardstick

I'm trying to generate ROC curve and precision-recall curve using the library "yardstick". However, I could not find a way to modify the figure shape. Here's a toy example.

```r
## Precision-recall curve
data.frame(true = as.factor(rep(c(0,1), 10)), 
           pred = runif(20)) %>% 
  pr_curve(truth = true, pred) %>% 
  autoplot()

## ROC curve
data.frame(true = as.factor(rep(c(0,1), 10)), 
           pred = runif(20)) %>% 
  roc_curve(truth = true, pred) %>% 
  autoplot()
```

When you run the codes, the generated figures look like below;
[image]
[image]

The top figure (ROC curve) is in a square form, while the bottom one (precision-recall curve) is a rectangle.

I've tried to

- change `width` and `height` options in `pdf` function
- change different options supported by ggplot2 (e.g. `plot.margin` using `theme`)

but could not find a good way to make two figures in the same shape.

How could I unify their shapes (or forms)?

Any comment will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coord_fixed()` from ggplot2 will do the trick. Note that you also need the adapt `xlim` and `ylim` if you want the plot area to be a square.

```r
pr_curve(tmp1, truth = true, pred) %>% 
    autoplot() +
    coord_fixed(xlim = 0:1, ylim = 0:1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on your answer, I found that I can also adjust the relative size of x, y axes by `ratio` option in `coord_fixed`.